# Java CSV to SQL file size issue

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, csv, filesize

I am monitoring a **CSV** file and I am importing to Postgres with the following procedure:

1. Load the file into an ArrayList (DATE_TIME,MEASUREMENT)
2. Get the latest DATE_TIME from the database
3. Iterate through the ArrayList
   ->If DATE_TIME > latest Then update database
   ->If DATE_TIME < latest Then don't care

Works fine for half an hour but when the file starts getting larger it's having trouble to digest it. So I figured I need to process each line in the **CSV** file only once.

Bulk loading the **CSV** to the database is out of the question also because of the file size and the frequency of required **UI** updates.

What would be a nice way to keep track where my last read of the file was - and resume the read from that point on wards the next time the thread runs?

Comment: "*Bulk loading the CSV to the database is out of the question*" - why? How big is the file? How many rows does it contain? Did you try loading it using the `COPY` command into a staging table?

Comment: Is the file in question one that gets only extended over time with new information? If so, then you could use 'RandomAccessFile' class to start where you ended the last scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is large, you should not load it in memory only to iterate through an array. You should change your procedure to :

> 1. Open the file
> 2. Get the latest DATE_TIME from the database
> 3. Iterate through the file getting (DATE_TIME,MEASUREMENT)
>
>    - If DATE_TIME > latest Then update database
>    - If DATE_TIME < latest Then don't care
> 4. Close the file

And if your file is **very** large, you should considere to commit changes in database at regular intervals.

Now for you question : the simplest way to be able to restart at the point where you stopped with the *file reading* procedure is to copy the remaining of the file (since the last read) to a new temporary file, delete the file and rename the temporary file with the original name.

Comment: I like this, I will try to filter the lines at BufferReader level. Then load the ones I need into the ArrayList to build up the query. Also I think I will be saving the last line I read somewhere and do no checks for lines before that - discard them anyway, to save up the if statement CPU cycles.